# Icon position in textField

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uitextfield

I would like a textfield with in an appropriate shortcut like this:
[image]

my code is this:

```
let imageViewUsername = UIImageView();
    let imageUsername = UIImage(named: "icon_username.png");
    imageViewUsername.image = imageUsername;
    imageViewUsername.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    imageViewUsername.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    txtUsername.leftView = imageViewUsername;
    txtUsername.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    txtUsername.addSubview(imageViewUsername)
```

I get completely moved icon to the left, at the beginning of the textfield. as it moves?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and it is working as expected, you can see my code:
[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // Creating ImageView
  let imageView = UIImageView()
  // Downloading an image
  imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png")!)!)
  imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
  imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 100)

  // Creating TextField
  let textField = UITextField()
  textField.placeholder = "Username"
  textField.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 100)

  // Setting up TextField with ImageView
  textField.leftView = imageView
  textField.leftViewMode = .Always

  // Showing the TextField on the ViewController's View
  self.view.addSubview(textField)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of X=0 , you can move the X values as per your requirement. as if 10-20 will be good. , Change the height and width WRT to textfield.
Updated code:

```
let imageViewUsername = UIImageView();
let imageUsername = UIImage(named: "icon_username.png");
imageViewUsername.image = imageUsername;
imageViewUsername.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: txtUsername.frame.height, height: txtUsername.frame.height) // Updated value.
imageViewUsername.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
txtUsername.addSubview(imageViewUsername)
```

Comment: can u pls post the latest screen shot @nunziogiuliocaggegi

Comment: check.@nunziogiuliocaggegi